# Can't insert same element again and again at the beginning in LinkedList

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def create_list():
    seq = input("Enter the sequence of integers: ").split()
    int_seq = [int(i) for i in seq]
    head = None
    tail = None
    for number in int_seq:
        if number == -1:
            break
        node = Node(number)
        if head is None:
            head = node
            tail = node
        else:
            tail.next = node
            tail = node

    return head, tail

def count_no_of_elements(head):
    if head is None:
        return 0
    curr = head
    counter = 0
    while curr:
        curr = curr.next
        counter += 1
    return counter

def insert_element(head, tail, elem, posn):
    no_of_elem = count_no_of_elements(head)
    if posn <= 0 or posn > no_of_elem + 1:
        return -1, -1

    if posn == 1:       # Insert at the beginning
        element = Node(elem)
        element.next = head
        head = element
        return head, tail

    else:           
        counter = 1
        curr = head
        while counter != (posn - 1):
            curr = curr.next
            counter += 1
        element = Node(elem)
        if curr.next is not None: # Insert in between
            element.next = curr.next 
            curr.next = element
        else:                      # Insert at the end
            curr.next = element
            tail = element
        return head, tail

def traverse_list(head):
    if head is None:
        return -1
    curr = head
    while curr:
        print(curr.data)
        curr = curr.next
    return head
```

After creating the list with the sequence: `1 3 5 7 9 2 4 8 6 0 -1` ,

I'm trying to insert `0` at the beginning for 3 times in a row.

Driver code:

```
list_head, list_tail = create_list()
# 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 8 6 0 -1

ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
if ins_hd != -1:
    trav = count_no_of_elements(ins_hd)
    print(trav)
    print('\n\n')
else:
    print(ins_hd)

if ins_hd != 1:
    trav = traverse_list(ins_hd)
print(in_tl.data)
```

The insertion code doesn't work the 2nd time onwards.

Actual Output:

```
11



0
1
3
5
7
9
2
4
8
6
0
0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `NameError: name 'traverse_list' is not defined`

Comment: @JohnGordon try now. Have added the traverse_list function too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the return value from your function, you must stop using the old values of the head and tail. You need to continue with the new values that you got back from the insertion. Currently you don't do that:

```
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
ins_hd, in_tl = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
# ...
```

Change that to use the same variables:

```
list_head, list_tail = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
list_head, list_tail = insert_element(list_head, list_tail, 0, 1)
# ...
```

And in the code that follows after those statements also use `list_head`, and `list_tail`.

#### Making it more object oriented

I would also suggest to create a class for your linked list, so that it maintains the changing values for its head and tail as part of its state. This makes for cleaner code, certainly when you start using multiple linked lists in the same code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, int_seq=[]):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        for number in int_seq:
            node = Node(number)
            if self.head is None:
                self.head = node
            else:
                self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node

    def size(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        curr = self.head
        count = 0
        while curr:
            curr = curr.next
            count += 1
        return count

    def insert(self, elem, posn=1):
        if posn == 1:    # Insert before head
            node = Node(elem)
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node
            return
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next is not None and posn > 2:
            curr = curr.next
            posn -= 1
        if posn != 2:
            raise ValueError("Invalid position")
        node = Node(elem)
        node.next = curr.next
        curr.next = node
        if curr == self.tail: # Insert after tail
            self.tail = node
        else:                 # Insert in between
            curr.next = node

    def values(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            yield curr.data
            curr = curr.next

seq = input("Enter the sequence of integers: ").split()
llist = LinkedList([int(i) for i in seq])
# 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 8 6 0

llist.insert(0, 1)
print("size: {}".format(llist.size()))
print("values: {}".format(list(llist.values())))
llist.insert(10, 12)
print("size: {}".format(llist.size()))
print("values: {}".format(list(llist.values())))
llist.insert(11, 5)
print("size: {}".format(llist.size()))
print("values: {}".format(list(llist.values())))
```

In the above code, I kept the same notion of `posn`, so that inserting at position 1 means that the insertion will happen *before* the head node. Many will find it more natural to actually define that as position 0, but I left it as it was.

I don't see the point for dealing differently with input value -1, as you can just read and insert all values, so I removed that logic.

When the given insertion position is out of range, I think it is more appropriate to raise an exception.

Also, it is overkill to count the number of elements to determine whether the position is within range, as you any way need to iterate over the list. So you can determine the validity of the position in *that* iteration.